# Comparar quantidade de colunas entre tabelas?

Tags: mysql

Tenho um sistema online e sempre estou atualizando ele na minha máquina local, e sempre faço alterações nas colunas da tabela. Gostaria de saber se existe um script onde posso fazer comparação de quantidade de colunas em tabelas de 2 banco e assim ele me sinalizar que existe diferença e em qual tabela pra eu poder atualizar.

Comment: Isso pode ajudar https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/quantos-indices-colunas-e-linhas-tem-cada-tabela/

Comment: Deu certinho ismael muito grato pela sua ajuda!!

Comment: @Eduardo Marque sua pergunta como duplicada. Não crie uma resposta.